# Wordpress wp_get_attachment_metadata() not working properly when called from plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

Im trying to use `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` function on a plugin. It is calling the function, and inside I try to fetch the metadata information of the attachment.

```
$file = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, false);
```

The problem is that this code is only returning the metadata for image files (png, jpg) even though the other file types are configured and are being uploaded properly. (I can see the other files in the media list, but, I can't access their metadata with this function).

Please have a look at the code that grabs the metadata:

```
add_filter( 'fu_is_debug', '__return_true' );

add_action( 'fu_after_upload', 'my_fu_after_upload', 10, 3 );
function my_fu_after_upload( $attachment_ids, $success, $post_id ) {
    // do something with freshly uploaded files
    // This happens on POST request, so $_POST will also be available for you
    $dest_folder = "/exports/data/".$post_id;

    echo "FUNCTION AFTER UPLOAD: " . "<br>attachment_ids=";
    print_r($attachment_ids);
    echo "<br>result=". $success . "<br>post_id=". $post_id ;
    print_r($_POST);

    $post_name = get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id, "");
    echo "Post name = " . $post_name . "<br>";

    if (!is_dir($dest_folder))
        mkdir($dest_folder);
    $upload_dir =  wp_upload_dir();
    echo "Upload dir<br>";
    print_r($upload_dir);

    foreach ($attachment_ids as $attachment_id) {
        printf("Getting attacments to atta %d <br>", $attachment_id);
        $file = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, false);
        print_r($file);
        echo "<br>";
        $file = $file['file'];
        $source_file = $upload_dir['basedir'] .'/'. $file;
        // Get the last name of the file, ie for /2013/07/file.img returns file.img
        $file = explode('/', $file);
        $file = $file[count($file) - 1];
        // Get the file extension
        $f_extension = explode('.', $file);
        if (count($f_extension) < 2 ) {
            $f_extension = "";
        } else {
            $f_extension = $f_extension[count($f_extension) - 1];
        }

        $dest_file = $dest_folder . '/' . $_POST['ra'] . '.' . $f_extension;

        printf("Copying '%s' to '%s'<br>", $source_file, $dest_file);
        // TODO: Verificar se não existe o arquivo antes
        copy($source_file, $dest_file);

    }
    flush();
}

add_action('fu_upload_result', 'my_fu_upload_result', 10, 2 );
function my_fu_upload_result( $layout, $result ) {
    // do something
    echo "FUNCTION UPLOAD RESULT: " . "<br>layout=" . $layout .
        "<br>result=". $result;
    print_r($_POST);

}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/sombrafam/426dad85eb390c9b6082

The screen log of a image file:

```
FUNCTION AFTER UPLOAD: 
attachment_ids=Array ( [0] => 121 ) 
result=1
post_id=32Array ( [post_ID] => 32 [post_title] => Erlon Cruz [ra] => 123456 [action] => upload_ugc [form_layout] => image [fu_nonce] => d71734168a [_wp_http_referer] => /?p=32 [ff] => f3c01b8520a3bdaf1f0141dd2b20f488 [form_post_id] => 32 ) Post name = Trabalho 1 - (ICA)
Upload dir
Array ( [path] => /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07 [url] => http://www.erloncruz.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/07 [subdir] => /2014/07 [basedir] => /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads [baseurl] => http://www.erloncruz.com.br/wp-content/uploads [error] => ) Getting attacments to atta 121 
Array ( [width] => 940 [height] => 168 [file] => 2014/07/banner1.png [sizes] => Array ( [thumbnail] => Array ( [file] => banner1-150x150.png [width] => 150 [height] => 150 [mime-type] => image/png ) [medium] => Array ( [file] => banner1-300x53.png [width] => 300 [height] => 53 [mime-type] => image/png ) ) [image_meta] => Array ( [aperture] => 0 [credit] => [camera] => [caption] => [created_timestamp] => 0 [copyright] => [focal_length] => 0 [iso] => 0 [shutter_speed] => 0 [title] => ) ) 
Copying '/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/banner1.png' to '/exports/data/32/123456.png'

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/frontend-uploader/lib/php/functions.php on line 312
FUNCTION UPLOAD RESULT: 
layout=image
result=ArrayArray ( [post_ID] => 32 [post_title] => Erlon Cruz [ra] => 123456 [action] => upload_ugc [form_layout] => image [fu_nonce] => d71734168a [_wp_http_referer] => /?p=32 [ff] => f3c01b8520a3bdaf1f0141dd2b20f488 [form_post_id] => 32 ) 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/sombrafam/c3bea65068e4c1b3b039

And a log of a pdf upload:

```
FUNCTION AFTER UPLOAD: 
attachment_ids=Array ( [0] => 122 ) 
result=1
post_id=32Array ( [post_ID] => 32 [post_title] => Erlon Cruz [ra] => 123456 [action] => upload_ugc [form_layout] => image [fu_nonce] => d71734168a [_wp_http_referer] => /?p=32 [ff] => f3c01b8520a3bdaf1f0141dd2b20f488 [form_post_id] => 32 ) Post name = Trabalho 1 - (ICA)
Upload dir
Array ( [path] => /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07 [url] => http://www.erloncruz.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/07 [subdir] => /2014/07 [basedir] => /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads [baseurl] => http://www.erloncruz.com.br/wp-content/uploads [error] => ) Getting attacments to atta 122 


Warning: Illegal string offset 'file' in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/frontend-uploader/lib/php/functions.php on line 285

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/frontend-uploader/lib/php/functions.php on line 285
Copying '/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/' to '/exports/data/32/123456.'

Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/frontend-uploader/lib/php/functions.php on line 302

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/frontend-uploader/lib/php/functions.php on line 312
FUNCTION UPLOAD RESULT: 
layout=image
result=ArrayArray ( [post_ID] => 32 [post_title] => Erlon Cruz [ra] => 123456 [action] => upload_ugc [form_layout] => image [fu_nonce] => d71734168a [_wp_http_referer] => /?p=32 [ff] => f3c01b8520a3bdaf1f0141dd2b20f488 [form_post_id] => 32 ) 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/sombrafam/bfdd531bbfa97e34f28d

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on my development environment, and it is not pulling data on PDFs. I know that isn't exactly the answer you want to hear, but it looks like that is the intended functionality.